# No embedded Image appear in xamarinForm

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, embedded-resource

Iam newbie to XamarinForms and I use **visual Studio 2017**.
I want to add embeddedImage to my app so to the "imagepage.xaml" file I added:

```
 embeddedImg.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("XFDemo.Images.baby.jpg");
```

and in "imagepage.xaml.cs" I added:

```html
<Image  x:Name="embeddedImg" Aspect="AspectFill" />
```

**but no image appear in the app.** just a blank page I can see.
please note that the image exist in PCL project inside "Images" folder and I set the "Action Build" of the image to **"Embedded resource"**.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin

Comment: If you give your xaml Image tag a height request does it show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found the solution ...
thats happened because Iam using xamarin live player and there is some limitations with xamarin live player one of these limitations is embedded resources.
check the following link to see those limitations:

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations)